# Validation of certain Action's methods in Struts2

Tags: java, validation, struts2

I have an Action class with CRUD actions inside and I have overridden the validate() method given by the ActionSupport class.

The question is: how can I fire the validation only for the update and create actions?

One possible solution is to move create & update on a brand new Action class, but I'd like to know if there's another solution for this.

Thanks!
Roberto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the two options are : refactor the validatable methods into a new action  (as you said), or switch to programmatic validation (instead of declarative). Basically,  call `myvalidate()` from inside your update/create methods, and return `INPUT` if there are errors.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try the @SkipValidation annotation with the method you don't want to be validated:

```
@SkipValidation
public String yourMethod(){
...
return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the other methods by putting an exclusion in your configuration file.

```
<interceptor-ref name="validation">
  <param name="validateAnnotatedMethodOnly">true</param>                
  <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Struts defaultStack of interceptors, you are already excluding validation from methods called input, back, cancel, or browse.

I recommend making your own interceptor stack (default for all actions, so you don't have to re-define these things for each action).  Base it on the example stack from struts-default.xml that suits you, and then edit the interceptor-ref for validation and workflow (these are closely related -- the workflow interceptor is the one that skips the action and returns the "input" action if there are validation errors -- so the method exclusions should match).

In my current project, I added in exceptions for *Form and *Input, so that validation kicks off by default, but it's easy to avoid -- just make sure the action method you're calling ends in Form or Input.

It's generally better to run validation by default (and define exceptions), because if you make a mistake and validation runs when you don't want it, you'll know immediately (your action won't execute due to errors).. whereas if you make a mistake and validation *doesn't* run, this is a silent failure.